# Ordenar valores de las columnas de mayor a menor en un arreglo y guardar cada valor ordenado en una nueva variable

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Los datos del cuadro azul existen, los datos del cuadro rojo debo registrarlos,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es  ordenar los(datos del cuadro azul) de mayor a menor y pasarlos a columna del cuadro rojo, según su orden.

Lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora:

```
                CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
                PROCEDURE PLANILLA_ROTACIONES_25_O01()
                BEGIN


                  declare TOT_M_01 INT (20);
                  declare TOT_M_02 INT (20);
                  declare TOT_M_03 INT (20);
                  declare TOT_M_04 INT (20);
                  declare TOT_M_05 INT (20);
                  declare TOT_M_06 INT (20);
                  declare TOT_M_07 INT (20);
                  declare TOT_M_08 INT (20);
                  declare TOT_M_09 INT (20);
                  declare TOT_M_10 INT (20);
                  declare TOT_M_11 INT (20);
                  declare TOT_M_12 INT (20);


                  DECLARE no_hay_mas_registros INT DEFAULT 0; 
                  DECLARE elCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT CODIGO  FROM PLANILLA_ROTACIONES ;





                      open elCursor;
                      -- se van tomando los datos hasta que el cursor llegue al final
                      bucle: loop

                      fetch elCursor into codigo_new;
                        if (no_hay_mas_registros = 1) then
                            leave bucle;
                        end if;

                      // comentario: aca tomo el datoy lo guardo en una variable
                      SET TOT_M_01 = (SELECT TOTAL_M_01 FROM planilla_rotaciones WHERE CODIGO=codigo_new); 
                      SET TOT_M_02 = (SELECT TOTAL_M_02 FROM planilla_rotaciones WHERE CODIGO=codigo_new);
                      SET TOT_M_03 = (SELECT TOTAL_M_03 FROM planilla_rotaciones WHERE CODIGO=codigo_new);
                      SET TOT_M_04 = (SELECT TOTAL_M_04 FROM planilla_rotaciones WHERE CODIGO=codigo_new);
                      SET TOT_M_05 = (SELECT TOTAL_M_05 FROM planilla_rotaciones WHERE CODIGO=codigo_new);
                      SET TOT_M_06 = (SELECT TOTAL_M_06 FROM planilla_rotaciones WHERE CODIGO=codigo_new);
                      SET TOT_M_07 = (SELECT TOTAL_M_07 FROM planilla_rotaciones WHERE CODIGO=codigo_new);
                      SET TOT_M_08 = (SELECT TOTAL_M_08 FROM planilla_rotaciones WHERE CODIGO=codigo_new);
                      SET TOT_M_09 = (SELECT TOTAL_M_09 FROM planilla_rotaciones WHERE CODIGO=codigo_new);
                      SET TOT_M_10 = (SELECT TOTAL_M_10 FROM planilla_rotaciones WHERE CODIGO=codigo_new);
                      SET TOT_M_11 = (SELECT TOTAL_M_11 FROM planilla_rotaciones WHERE CODIGO=codigo_new);
                      SET TOT_M_12 = (SELECT TOTAL_M_12 FROM planilla_rotaciones WHERE CODIGO=codigo_new);



                      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Temporal AS (
                       SELECT CODIGO, 
                       GROUP_CONCAT(TOT_M_01,
                                    TOT_M_02,
                                    TOT_M_03,
                                    TOT_M_04,
                                    TOT_M_05,
                                    TOT_M_06,
                                    TOT_M_07,
                                    TOT_M_08,
                                    TOT_M_09,
                                    TOT_M_10,
                                    TOT_M_11,
                                    TOT_M_12
                       order by Columnas DESC) ColumnasOrdenadas
                       FROM ( SELECT  CODIGO,
                                   (case when n = 1 then TOTAL_M_01
                                         when n = 2 then TOTAL_M_02
                                         when n = 3 then TOTAL_M_03
                                         when n = 4 then TOTAL_M_04
                                         when n = 5 then TOTAL_M_05
                                         when n = 6 then TOTAL_M_06
                                         when n = 7 then TOTAL_M_07
                                         when n = 8 then TOTAL_M_08
                                         when n = 9 then TOTAL_M_09
                                         when n = 10 then TOTAL_M_10
                                         when n = 11 then TOTAL_M_11
                                         when n = 12 then TOTAL_M_12
                                    end
                                   ) as Columnas
                        from PLANILLA_ROTACIONES a 
                        cross join (select 1 as n union all select 2 
                                                  union all select 3 
                                                  union all select 3 
                                                  union all select 4
                                                  union all select 5 
                                                  union all select 6 
                                                  union all select 7 
                                                  union all select 8
                                                  union all select 9 
                                                  union all select 10 
                                                  union all select 11 
                                                  union all select 12) n
                    ) T
                    GROUP BY CODIGO
                );





                     IF (SELECT count(CODIGO) as conteo from PLANILLA_ROTACIONES WHERE  CODIGO  = codigo_new ) = 1 THEN 




                         UPDATE PLANILLA_ROTACIONES  E
                         INNER JOIN Temporal T ON E.CODIGO = T.CODIGO
                         SET o_01 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 1), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                             o_02 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 2), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                             o_03 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 3), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                             o_04 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 4), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                             o_05 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 5), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                             o_06 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 6), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                             o_07 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 7), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                             o_08 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 8), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                             o_09 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 9), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                             o_10 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 10), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                             o_11 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 11), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                             o_12 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 12), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER);


                      END IF;





                    end loop bucle;
                  close elCursor;



                END
```

Necesito ideas de como podría hacer ese arreglo de mayor a menor, si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien no conozco en profundidad `MySQL` entiendo que lo que buscas no es nada sencillo de resolver desde SQL. Sin duda esta es una tarea que debieras dejarla en manos del "front-end". Aun así, si lo debes resolver desde la base de datos, lo que se me ocurre que podrías hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Transponer las columnas de interés en nuevas filas (esto para poder ordenar)
2. Concatenar todas las columnas (separadas por `,`) en un sola fila por cada  `ID` original y ordenadas por el valor
3. Actualizar las nuevas columnas de la tabla original con el resultado del paso anterior

Esto básicamente a nivel conceptual, ahora te presento un ejemplo sencillo , que deberías adaptarlo a tu estructura de datos, es fundamental que cuentes con un `ID` por fila, puede ser uno existente o eventualmente deberías generar uno nuevo. El ejemplo es solo con 3 columnas para que sea sencillo de entender.

#### En primer lugar, creamos una tabla de Ejemplo

```
create table Ejemplo (
  ID    INT,
  TOTAL_M_01  INT,
  TOTAL_M_02  INT,
  TOTAL_M_03  INT,
  O_01 INT,
  O_02 INT,
  O_03 INT
);

INSERT INTO Ejemplo (ID, TOTAL_M_01, TOTAL_M_02, TOTAL_M_03) values (1,3,5,1);
INSERT INTO Ejemplo (ID, TOTAL_M_01, TOTAL_M_02, TOTAL_M_03) values (2,2,6,7);
INSERT INTO Ejemplo (ID, TOTAL_M_01, TOTAL_M_02, TOTAL_M_03) values (3,6,1,3);

+---+----+------------+------------+------------+------+------+------+
| # | ID | TOTAL_M_01 | TOTAL_M_02 | TOTAL_M_03 | O_01 | O_02 | O_03 |
+---+----+------------+------------+------------+------+------+------+
| 1 | 1  | 3          | 5          | 1          | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+---+----+------------+------------+------------+------+------+------+
| 2 | 2  | 2          | 6          | 7          | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+---+----+------------+------------+------------+------+------+------+
| 3 | 3  | 6          | 1          | 3          | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+---+----+------------+------------+------------+------+------+------+
```

La idea es actualizar las columnas `O_01` a `O_03` con los valores ordenados de las columnas `TOTAL_M_*`.

#### Crear temporal con los valores ordenados, concatenados y separados por `,`

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Temporal AS (
SELECT ID, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(Columnas order by Columnas DESC) ColumnasOrdenadas
       FROM ( SELECT  ID,
                   (case when n = 1 then TOTAL_M_01
                         when n = 2 then TOTAL_M_02
                         when n = 3 then TOTAL_M_03
                    end
                   ) as Columnas
        from Ejemplo a 
        cross join (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n
    ) T
    GROUP BY ID
);

+---+----+-------------------+
| # | ID | ColumnasOrdenadas |
+---+----+-------------------+
| 1 | 1  | 5,3,1             |
+---+----+-------------------+
| 2 | 2  | 7,6,2             |
+---+----+-------------------+
| 3 | 3  | 6,3,1             |
+---+----+-------------------+
```

Ya tenemos por cada fila original, los valores de las columnas originales ordenados, ahora solo queda actualizar la tabla original

#### Actualizar las nuevas columnas

```
UPDATE Ejemplo E
       INNER JOIN Temporal T
           ON E.ID = T.ID
       SET O_01 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 1), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           O_02 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 2), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           O_03 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 3), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER);
```

Y ahora podemos constatar el resultado final:

```
+---+----+------------+------------+------------+------+------+------+
| # | ID | TOTAL_M_01 | TOTAL_M_02 | TOTAL_M_03 | O_01 | O_02 | O_03 |
+---+----+------------+------------+------------+------+------+------+
| 1 | 1  | 3          | 5          | 1          | 5    | 3    | 1    |
+---+----+------------+------------+------------+------+------+------+
| 2 | 2  | 2          | 6          | 7          | 7    | 6    | 2    |
+---+----+------------+------------+------------+------+------+------+
| 3 | 3  | 6          | 1          | 3          | 6    | 3    | 1    |
+---+----+------------+------------+------------+------+------+------+
```

para probar, tienes este [Fiddle](http://rextester.com/EGT32796)

#### Una ayudita más

No me voy a meter en como se define un `stored procedure` y si lo estás haciendo bien o no, por que no es parte de la pregunta y no lo tengo muy claro, lo que sí puedo decirte es que esta solución NO necesita el cursor para nada, borra toda esa parte. El único código que necesitarías es el que ya has adaptado de mi respuesta

```
-- Creamos y completamos la tabla temporal
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Temporal AS (
       SELECT CODIGO, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(TOT_M_01,
                    TOT_M_02,
                    TOT_M_03,
                    TOT_M_04,
                    TOT_M_05,
                    TOT_M_06,
                    TOT_M_07,
                    TOT_M_08,
                    TOT_M_09,
                    TOT_M_10,
                    TOT_M_11,
                    TOT_M_12
       order by Columnas DESC) ColumnasOrdenadas
       FROM ( SELECT  CODIGO,
                   (case when n = 1 then TOTAL_M_01
                         when n = 2 then TOTAL_M_02
                         when n = 3 then TOTAL_M_03
                         when n = 4 then TOTAL_M_04
                         when n = 5 then TOTAL_M_05
                         when n = 6 then TOTAL_M_06
                         when n = 7 then TOTAL_M_07
                         when n = 8 then TOTAL_M_08
                         when n = 9 then TOTAL_M_09
                         when n = 10 then TOTAL_M_10
                         when n = 11 then TOTAL_M_11
                         when n = 12 then TOTAL_M_12
                    end
                   ) as Columnas
        from PLANILLA_ROTACIONES a 
        cross join (select 1 as n union all select 2 
                                  union all select 3 
                                  union all select 3 
                                  union all select 4
                                  union all select 5 
                                  union all select 6 
                                  union all select 7 
                                  union all select 8
                                  union all select 9 
                                  union all select 10 
                                  union all select 11 
                                  union all select 12) n
    ) T
    GROUP BY CODIGO
);


-- Para verificar antes de actualizar 
-- correr solo hasta este select
SELECT CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 1), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 2), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 3), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 4), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 5), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 6), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 7), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 8), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 9), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 10), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 11), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
       CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 12), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER)
       FROM PLANILLA_ROTACIONES  E
       INNER JOIN Temporal T ON E.CODIGO = T.CODIGO


-- Si los resultados son los eperados podremos actualizar las tablas definitivas
UPDATE PLANILLA_ROTACIONES  E
       INNER JOIN Temporal T ON E.CODIGO = T.CODIGO
       SET o_01 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 1), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           o_02 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 2), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           o_03 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 3), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           o_04 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 4), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           o_05 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 5), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           o_06 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 6), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           o_07 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 7), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           o_08 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 8), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           o_09 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 9), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           o_10 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 10), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           o_11 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 11), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER),
           o_12 = CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(T.ColumnasOrdenadas, ',', 12), ',', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER);
```

Comment: Estoy ansioso por probrar el codigo, pero antes unas consultas:
la tabla ejemplo no es necesaria verdad? puedo obtener el identificador único de cada dato.

La tabla temporal se ejecuta solo para la consulta?

Comment: La tabla `Ejemplo` haría las veces de la tuya: `PLANILLA_ROTACIONES`, si tienes un `ID` único por fila, deberías poder adaptar los dos últimos bloques de código a tus necesidades. 1) En el `case when n = 1 then TOTAL_M_01` deberías agregar los `case` para las columnas adicionales, b) En ` cross join (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n ` deberías agregar tantos `union` como columnas adicionales tengas. Y por ultimo c) En  `SET O_01 = ....` agregar a continuación la actualización de las columnas que falten con el índice de cada una.

Comment: `codigo_new` es una variable que declaras por que estás usando un cursor, la variable real es `CODIGO` si no entendí mal y si `CODIGO` es la PK de cada fila  lo que en definitiva debes reemplazar  es `ID` por `CODIGO` en el ejemplo, te sugiero por seguridad que pruebes primero con una copia de la tabla original, no?

Comment: Si entendiste bien, lo que yo aun no entiendo es cuando declaras 1,2,3 en los `WHEN`, nose si llamas en duro al `ID`? o si le estas dando una variable para luego trabajar con ella..

Comment: No, esos son números generados que se usan para identificar el orden o posición de cada columna, el 1 me indicaría que se trata de `TOTAL_M_01` y luego para saber que hay que actualizar `O_01` y así.. Si tienes 12 columnas de totales, deberías tener 12 `when` y la subconsulta `(select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3)` hacer que te devuelva 12 filas de 1 a 12.

Comment: acabo de editar el codigo de mi pregunta principal, me ayudas a revisarlo? creo que puedo tener errores. en la concatenacion talves

Comment: Acabo de agregar una edición a mi respuesta

Comment: al menos yo probé con la edición que realice en mi post, y no funciono.
pienso que en el algoritmos de la tabla temporal me debe estar fallando algo, de todos modos correré esta versión tuya .